# How to display the data from multiple tables (POJO) in a single report

Tags: spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I am using *Spring 3*, *iReport*, *JasperReports 4.5.0* to generate the reports. I have three tables like below.

<kbd>**TableName**</kbd><kbd>**Fields**</kbd>                    
<kbd>DN</kbd>             <kbd>date</kbd>                        
<kbd>DNProd</kbd>      <kbd>prodName, prodQty</kbd>
<kbd>DNPay</kbd>       <kbd>cost, totalCost</kbd>

The problem is I need to show *date, prodName, prodQty, cost, totalCost* fields in a single report. But these are pointing to different *POJO* classes.I have searched in google for this and found some solution like use sub reports. 
But as i am new to these reports i don't know whether it is correct solution or not. Can any one point me in the right direction with any sample if possible.

Comment: What datasource are you planning to use?

Answer (score 0):

As per my suggestion DynamicJasper suits best in your situation.
You need to right and HQL that will get all the fields described by you in the question from the respective POJOs with proper joins.

And on executing this HQL you will get the List. That you have to pass to DynamicJasper to build the report for you. It will automatically get the column names from the pojo field names.

Below is the example for the same.

```
Session session = null;
        try {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            List list = session.createQuery("from Employee").list();

            session.getTransaction().commit();

            DynamicReport dynamicReport = new ReflectiveReportBuilder(list).build();
            dynamicReport.setTitle("List of Employees");
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(dynamicReport, new ClassicLayoutManager(), list);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "C:\\TestDynamicJasper.pdf"); 
            resp.getWriter().write("Welcome to Show Report");
            resp.getWriter().flush();
            resp.getWriter().close();
        } catch (JRException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ColumnBuilderException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(session != null)
                session.close();
        }
```

Hope this helps you. :)